# Post a photo album to a page

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook app that currently post an photo on the logged user webpage.

```
$upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Everything works like a charm, but now I need to post the photo to a page of which I am the admin.

I tried.

```
$upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/**pagename**/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

With no luck. How can I do this?
I don't need fancy permission because the app will only use my credential and I'm the admin of the page.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you tried using the page id instead of the page name?

Answer (score 2):

In order for your app to perform these privileged operations, the user must grant your app the `manage_pages` permission

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/